# What git gotchas have you been caught by?

Tags: git, version-control

The worst one I've been caught by was with git submodules.  I had a submodule for a project on github.  The project was unmaintained, and I wanted to submit patches, but couldn't, so I forked.  Now the submodule was pointing at the original library, and I needed it to point at the fork instead.  So I deleted the old submodule and replaced it with a submodule for the new project in the same commit.  Turns out that this broke everyone else's repositories.  I'm still not sure what the correct way of handling this situation is, but I ended up deleting the submodule, having everyone pull and update, and then I created the new submodule, and had everyone pull and update again.  It took the better portion of a day to figure that out.

What have other people done to accidentally screw up git repositories in non-obvious ways, and how did you resolve it?

Comment: This is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491766/what-are-common-antipatterns-of-using-git and the answers should be merged.

Comment: A "gotcha" isn't really the same thing as an "anti-pattern".  I asked about repository destruction, he asked about worst-practices.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The usual trailing slash when [adding a submodule](http://august.lilleaas.net/git_submodules):

> When you use git add on a submodule, make sure you don’t have a tailing slash.

```
> git add local/path
  -- adds the submodule

> git add local/path/
  -- adds all the files in the submodule directly into your repository, big no-no
```

Answer (score 13):

It's not a gotcha, it's a **git**cha.

Comment: Lol +1 funny -1 should have been a comment

Answer (score 7):

Publishing to public repository without realizing my `git config user.name` was incorrect.
That means the public repo now gets a name (and an email) I would rather not have published at all. If that repo is replicated, ... it is too late.

That is why I prefer having my user.name displayed in my git prompt shell, meaning instead of having this:

```
 MY_HOSTNAME /c/Prog/myGitProject (master)$
```

I see this:

```
 MY_HOSTNAME /c/Prog/myGitProject (master) VonC $
```

I know who I am from the very first command I type in this Git bash session!

Comment: Setting a global username that you're alright with tends to avoid that.

Comment: @Tchalvak: yes, but you have several local repos, each one needing a *different* name for pushing to their respective upstream (remote) repos... a global variable isn't enough.

Comment: Certainly, but that becomes a matter of setting a default name/email that you don't have a problem with having been made public, and only using more sensitive ones in specific cases.  *shrugs*

Answer (score 6):

1. Only realising you've [forgotten an entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887049/recovering-from-forgetting-to-gitignore) in `.gitignore` once you've got matches spread across a load of branches.
2. Forgetting that git add doesn't add what's not there...

   ```
   git add .
   git commit
   git status
   //hey! why didn't it commit my deletes?, Oh yeah, silly me
   git add -u
   git commit --amend
   ```
3. If you do a `git branch list`, you get a new branch called `list`, but if you do a `git stash`, you get your workspace stashed; for stash, you *need* the `list` if you want the list...

More soon, probably...

Comment: Apparently there's git add -A which does both

Comment: But what do you mean by "what's not there"?

Answer (score 3):

1. Work work work
2. Stash changes
3. Fetch latest
4. Rebase
5. Get conflicts, fix them
6. Forget to "git rebase --continue"
7. Pop stash
8. *Realize* I forgot to "git rebase --continue"
9. git rebase --abort
10. Changes I stashed originally - pfffft, gone.

Comment: No, it's a minor annoyance. Your stash is still in your repository, you just have to find it. If you still the hash displayed in your console session, there you go! If not, use 'git fsck' to locate it. See this SO answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/recover-dropped-stash-in-git

Answer (score 2):

Work work work ...

```
git commit
```

Work work work ...

```
git commit
```

Hm... time to integrate

```
git rebase -i origin/master
```

What? Conflicts? Let's start again

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Cry cry cry...

---

Git lets you wipe your local history without remorse. The biggest gotcha is that *you* are the safety net.

Comment: Well, hooray for `git reflog` then. :)

Comment: Does `git reflog` allow me to see the dropped commits? It only lists activity and I've made a `reset --hard` ( updated the answer, it was incorrect ).

Comment: `git reset --hard` is one of the major ways that it's actually possible shoot yourself in the foot.  As such, I never use it any more.  I just `git reset HEAD~1` and then `git checkout` individual files as necessary.

Comment: This is completely incorrect. Your history is still there, you just don't know how to find it. See 'git reflog' as a starting point. Find the commit you want, and make a branch to it.

Even if you somehow manage to lose all pointers to a commit, it doesn't get deleted by the gc for something like 30 days (configurable). See 'git fsck'.

It is really, really hard to actually lose something with git. With SVN, say, you'd probably not have committed those changes in the first place, so if you lose them, they're gone.

Comment: What command were you trying to type when you used `git reset --hard origin/master`?  Why would you do anything other than `git rebase --abort` to abort a failed rebase?

Answer (score 1):

One of my most embarrassing moments with a git repository, though it's more about sed:

I was once doing a `find ... -exec sed -i ...` operation in a subdirectory of my repository. I'd tested it without the `-i` first, got distracted, came back and managed to switch to the top directory in my repo before running it. Now, git's important files are all read-only, but `sed -i` by default shuffles the file away by renaming then writes back to the original, so it works just fine on a read-only file like git's objects. The substitution wasn't reversible, and I had to recover the repository by cloning and fetching from someone who tracked mine as a remote.

I never even thought for a moment that sed would work on read-only files. Moral of the story: use `sed -i -c`, which copies the file, then attempts to overwrite the original.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new branch:

```
git branch new-branch
```

Work, commit, work ... Realise all my work is on master, not on the new branch.

I should have done:

```
git checkout -b new-branch
```

Why can't I do something like:

```
git branch -c new-branch
```

(c for checkout) with an option to make that the default behaviour???

Comment: `git checkout -b new-branch` would have been the first thing to do. To fix that afterwards, `git checkout new-branch`, `git merge master` (same state on both branches now), `git checkout master` and finally `git reset --hard origin/master` to get your master back to its pristine state.

Answer (score 0):

Work work work. Start staging a change. Notice you don't want everything committed. Stage a partial commit carefully.

Eventually decide that this isn't ready for the current branch. I want to commit the staged changes to a new temporary branch. Sounds so trivial conceptually, right?

Google for how to do this. Top answer says `stash`, `checkout -b newbranch`, `stash pop`. Do this begrudgingly, wondering why there isn't an easier way.

Find that this completely wiped the distinction between your staged and unstaged changes. Thanks, Git!

Comment: Work work work. Stage a painfully careful partial commit over multiple iterations of `git status`, `git diff` and `git add`. Decide you're done, `git commit -a`. Wupwhaa :(

Comment: Just commit the changes in the current branch. Then, commit the remaining work in progress. Switch to a new branch, cherry-pick the commit there. In the previous branch, remove the unwanted change with `git revert` on the previously cherry-picked commit. Finally, `git reset @~3` there to pick up where you left off. ;-)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Yep, that's what I do now. Commit first, worry about branches later.