# Recovering from forgetting to .gitignore

Tags: git

I have been caught out by what appears to be a common enough problem for git newbies.

I forgot to .gitignore a particular file, and adding it to .gitignore after having committed makes no difference.

I found [this page on gitready](http://www.gitready.com/beginner/2009/03/06/ignoring-doesnt-remove-a-file.html) which explains how to remove a file from the repository without removing it from the working tree (by using the command `git rm --cached <file>`, which works ok, except that if I then try to merge that back into another branch, the files in the working tree get deleted.

Steps to reproduce, on an empty folder:

```
git init
touch want.txt
touch wantnot.txt
git add .
git commit -m "Initial"
git checkout -b BranchForIgnore
git rm --cached wantnot.txt
cat > .gitignore
wantnot.txt  [Ctrl-D Ctrl-D here to exit cat]
git add .
git commit -m "Ignoring file"
```

Up to here, everything is fine

```
git checkout master
git merge BranchForIgnore
```

At this point, my wantnot.txt files are no longer in my master, and obviously, checking out BranchForIgnore won't help either.

What to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *I forgot to .gitignore a particular file, and adding it to `.gitignore` after having committed makes no difference.*

Well, of course it doesn't.  Ignoring is about **untracked** files (which means files not under version control).

> *I found a page on gitready which explains how to remove a file from the repository without removing it from the working tree (by using the command `git rm --cached <file>`, which works ok, except that if I then try to merge that back into another branch, the files in the working tree get deleted.*

Git deletes file because you can recover it, as it was tracked in one branch.

The solution would be to commit "untracking" a file (removing file from version control) in all branches, using `git cherry-pick`, or making `git rm --cached <file> && git commit -a` on a separate commit branch, then merging this topic branch in all branches (and then recovering file from a tracked version).

Comment: Thanks for this. Given that files with the same name exist in many locations, how would I do 'recovering file from a tracked version'?

Comment: When you switch to a branch that lack given file, you can recover a file using e.g. `git checkout HEAD^ -- <file>`, or in more generic situation use `git log -2 --full-history -- <file>` to get the commit which last had the file and then recover file using `git checkout <commit> -- <file>` or `git show <commit>:<file>  >  <file>`.

Comment: Wow, that's some serious git-fu!

Comment: The git-fu is required only if you need to find a commit which last had the file.  The core is `git checkout <commit that has file> -- <file to be recovered>`.

Comment: Apparently this only works if I type in the exact location of the file(s), I was hoping for something that would work with wildcards (the way the rm did)

Comment: It doesn't work?  Doesn't e.g. `git checkout <commit> -- '*.xml'` work (don't forget '--' separator, don't forget using quotes to protect from shell expansion; also if I remember correctly paths are from top tree)?  It might not work, because not all commands support wildcards.

Comment: In the end, I went the back root - copied my entire working tree to another folder, deleted all the files by hand, modified gitignore, committed, then pasted working tree back... Did it on master.

Answer (score 6):

Rename the file to a temporary name (not using git), commit the deletion plus the .gitignore file, then rename the file back to its original name.

```
mv wantnot.txt wantnot.txt.tmp
git rm wantnot.txt
echo wantnot.txt >.gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "remove mistakenly committed wantnot.txt"
mv wantnot.txt.tmp wantnot.txt
```

Your use of a separate branch for this may be unnecessarily confusing the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Actually my problem is that I have already created several branches for other reasons, and I didn't want to have to perform this operation in all my branches (and even if I did, I wasn't too clear on what would happen when I start merging those changes).

Comment: I see. You may need to perform a similar operation on all your branches (a `git cherry-pick` may be useful for this). As you move between branches that track and don't track `wantnot.txt`, it may appear and disappear until you have everything sorted for all branches. Make sure you save a copy if this file is important.

Comment: Oh, and the actual file is AssemblyInfo.cs, so one in every project in my working tree, not sure if mv works for that (I'm not a unix command line expert, but amazingly git is seducing me)

Comment: At the worse, there's always filter-branch, this is a standalone, one developer repository, after all.

Comment: `mv` renames any file, even C# source files. :)

Comment: Oh really?! :) No, I meant whether it could rename recursively, my google-foo says no.

Comment: This worked really easily.