# git: how to not delete files when rebasing commits with file deletion

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I have a branch that I would like to rebase onto the lastest commit on my master. The problem is that one of the intervening commits on master was to delete and ignore a particular set of files (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887049/recovering-from-forgetting-to-gitignore)).

If I just do a straight rebase, those files will get deleted again. Is there anyway of doing this, *inside* git, rather than copying all the files out by hand, then copying them back in again afterwards?

Or should I do something like create a new branch off master, then merge in just the commits from the old branch?

Attempts ascii art:

```
master    branch
  |        w  work in progress on branch
  C        |  committed further changes on master
  |        |
  B        /  committed delete/ignore files on master
  |       2  committed changes on branch
  |      /  
  A     /  committed changes on master which I now need to get branch working
  |    1  committed changes on branch
  0___/  created branch
```

*(Doing the art, I realise that I could just rebase branch from A, then merge when I've finished, but I'd still like to know if there's a way to do this 'properly')*

**UPDATE** Warning to anyone trying this. The solution proposed here is fine, but when you checkout master again, the B commit will be re-applied, and you lose all your files again :(

Comment: Do you need only A, or A, C, and master HEAD for your branch?

Comment: @VonC, well, I originally thought all of them, but I could make do for the moment with just A. Ultimately, I would have liked to rebase at the end (when branch development is finished) to bring everything into the master 'stream', but I guess at the worse I could just merge at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment, I gather you need to rebase dev branch on top of master *except* B.
You do not want to see files you removed in one branch be removed in another.

One possible solution would be:

- `rebase --interactive` master to rewrite commits order (if possible)

```
    0--A--C'--B'  master
     \
      --1--2--w     dev
```

- rebase dev branch on top of C' (representing all the master commit except B)

```
    0--A--C'--B' master 
           \
            --1'--2'--w' dev
```

That means you do not have already pushed master to another repository (otherwise, that would involve a merge nightmare for those who wish to pull master in their own repo/master branch)

Comment: In the end, I went with rebasing on the commit before the one that 'hurts'. But the green tick is yours.