# What's the difference between `git add .` and `git add -u`?

Tags: git, git-add

I was assuming that both work in the same way. Both add every file onto index. But I seem wrong.

- What's the difference between `git add .` and `git add -u`?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It is one of the git gotchas [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597278/what-git-gotchas-have-you-been-caught-by/2117202#2117202) (pre Git 2.0).

`git add .` only adds what is there, not what has been deleted (if tracked).

```
git add .
git commit
git status
//hey! why didn't it commit my deletes?, Oh yeah, silly me
git add -u .
git commit --amend
```

`git add -A` would take care of both steps...

---

With [**Git 2.0, `git add -A` is default**](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f99a38c0121456822f8a9dfb7928eefceaa98201/Documentation/RelNotes/2.0.0.txt#L32-L36).

> `git add <path>` is the same as "`git add -A <path>`" now, so that
>   "`git add dir/`" will notice paths you removed from the directory and
>   record the removal.
>   In older versions of Git, "`git add <path>`" used to ignore removals.
>
> You can say "`git add --ignore-removal <path>`" to
>   add only added or modified paths in `<path>`, if you really want to.

---

Warning ([git1.8.3 April 2013, for upcoming git2.0](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.3.txt#L19-L30)).
I have modified my answer to say `git add -u .`, instead of `git add -u`.:

> `git add -u` will **operate on the entire tree** in Git 2.0 for consistency with "`git commit -a`" and other commands.
>   Because there will be no mechanism to make "`git add -u`" behave as "`git add -u .`", it is
>   important for those who are used to "`git add -u`" (without pathspec) updating the index only for paths in the current subdirectory to start training their fingers to explicitly say "`git add -u .`" when they mean it before Git 2.0 comes.

As I mentioned in "[e](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162511/6309)"

Comment: Thanks for your answer and an example. The "hey!" line really helps me.

Comment: @TK: yes, Benjol (http://stackoverflow.com/users/11410/benjol)'s example is a good one.

Comment: It seems we don't need to put the `.`(pathspec) with Git 2.x. It works find when I tested.

Comment: Also, from Git 2.0, `git add .` adds all changes to index as `-A` option is default. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26343584/524588

Comment: @Sangdol Thank you for this reminder. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Very helpful thanks. Unfortunately this is bad design. The property -u should have become the update command all by its own. Laziness? Mountain of technical debt?

Answer (score 26):

Like the manual says: `git add .` will add all files in the current directory, whereas `git add -u .` will only add those already being tracked.

Comment: `add -u` will also stage deletions.

Comment: only if the deleted file was tracked ;)

Comment: add -u is the commit -a equivalent, sort of(in files it operates on).

Comment: Bannier: If the deleted file wasn't tracked then there's nothing to be deleted from the staging area anyway?

Answer (score 14):

[git add documentaiton](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html)

```
git add .
```

add all files from the current directory

```
git add -u
```

only update files currently being tracked.

Comment: Perhaps cover differences between Git 2.0 and versions of Git before that?