# Autodeleting files from repository I've deleted manually from a working folder

Tags: git

I've working with git for pretty long time and still can figure out that. I **add** some files, I **delete** some files... When I want to commit, what do I do?

```
#1
git add .
git commit -m "123"
```

or

```
#2
git rm file1_I_removed
git rm file2_I_removed
git rm file3_I_removed
git rm file4_I_removed
git add .
git commit -m "123"
```

or

```
#3

git add -u
git commit -m "123"
```

Note that most probably I don't remember exactly what files I have deleted (even thought I can use `git status` and see them), and once I've **deleted** them, I want them **to be deleted from repository** as well without trying hard like

```
git rm file1_I_removed 
git rm file2_I_removed ... 
git rm fileN_I_removed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
git add -u
```

This command deletes all removed files, and updates what was modified.

If you have new files to add to the commit after that you can always `git add .` after.

Comment: +1. Note: depending on what deletion you need to record in the index, you might want to consider `git add -u .` (git1.8.3+): see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2190440/6309

Comment: But what about `git add -A .`?

Comment: `git add -A` . will do both `git add .` and git `add -u`, in that order. Maybe he doesn't want to add anything and just wants to delete removed files, that's why I proposed a `git add -u` and then, if desired, `git add .` Anyway, good note, |1