# Move and rename multiple files using git

Tags: git, rename

I'm trying to search on the web a way to rename all the files in a directory and move all the contents of that directory one level up inside another directory using `git`.

For example, replace "run" with ruin"

```
Directory a/b/c contains:
run1.txt
run2.txt
runner.txt
file.txt

Result: 
Directory a/d/ contains:
ruin1.txt
ruin2.txt
ruiner.txt
file.txt
```

Comment: Just rename the files like you normally would and then afterwards add the changes to Git. No need to make Git do the renames.

Comment: you can use git mv (https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mv.html)

Comment: As @poke said. Easier to do with your shell and Then commit the change.  Zmv is you use zsh can rename with Regex as opposed to doing them individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do move the files yourself (without git), then you would need a:

```
git add -A
```

That way, git will detect the changes. See "[What's the difference between `git add .` and `git add -u`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2190440/6309)": git will detect the additions *and* the deletions, and deduce from it the *moves*.