# git undo deleted files

Tags: git, git-rm, git-stage

I am new to git. I have checkout files from remote. I had to delete few files from the git repo. Instead of doing `git rm` command, I issued unix `rm -rf folder` command. I need to revert the delete command and then perform `git rm` command. How to revert to the latest code?

Note: I have not yet committed the staged files.The out out of `git status` is the list of files deleted in the below format:

```
#   deleted:    i18n/angular-locale_sl.js
#   deleted:    i18n/angular-locale_in.js
```

Comment: If you've already deleted the folder, git should detect that already, you just need to stage the deletion. What's the output of `git status`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restore a deleted file in a Git repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repo)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you discard unstaged changes in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704/how-do-you-discard-unstaged-changes-in-git)

Comment: @mbs that's not a good duplicate, that question involves committing the deletion. The original poster to this question doesn't appear to have staged and committed the change yet.

Comment: I have not yet committed the changes. The output of the 'git status' command is updated in the question.

Comment: Yeah, see, git detects that you've deleted the file already, so you just need to stage the change, you don't need to revert and then delete it again. Just do `git rm -r i18n`, or `git add -A i18n`, or `git add --all i18n`.

Answer (score 15):

> I need to revert the delete command and then perform git rm command. How to revert to the latest code?

Simply do a (since you haven't committed anything):

```
cd /root/of/your/repo
git checkout HEAD -- .
```

That will restore the working tree to the index.

(A `git reset --hard` should work too, but isn't needed here)

But you could also register those deletion to the index directly:

```
git add -A .
```

See "[What's the difference between `git add .` and `git add -u`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2190440/6309)"

Comment: Why doesn't "git checkout origin/master" do the same thing? At least the latter can remind me to stash the change before checking out or something.

Comment: @JohnJiang The actual command these days would be `git restore -- .` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309): the goal is to restore HEAD, which might have changed since the last fetch of `origin/master`

Answer (score 13):

If you have staged the deletion, first unstage it:

```
git reset HEAD path/to/deleted/file
```

Then restore the file:

```
git checkout path/to/deleted/file
```

Answer (score 6):

**Revert a git delete on your local machine**

You're wanting to undo of git rm or rm followed by git add:

Restore the file in the index:

`git reset -- <file>`

after that check out from index

`git checkout -- <file>`

for example:

```
git reset -- src/main/java/de/foo/bar.java
git checkout -- src/main/java/de/foo/bar.java
```

Answer (score 0):

To supplement [the answer by @VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23333223),

> I had to delete few files from the git repo. Instead of doing git rm command, I issued unix rm -rf folder command

The only difference between the two options is that `git rm` can also remove the files from your git index. However, because you never added them to the index to begin with, there is no particular reason to use `git rm`, and you don't need to undo the plain `/bin/rm`.

Answer (score -1):

I deleted a folder without committing the change. I was able to recover the folder  by simply using `git recover`

```
git recover name_of_deleted_folder
```

I had to spell the full name, that is `partial_name_of_deleted_folder*` did not work.

Comment: not a valid command as of git version 2.39.0 (very recent as of today)