# tips with git for private repo

Tags: git, bash, github

I just started working with a group and we have a private repo set up, and I am having a hell of a time finding any good sources for working with it. Im not to great with git so I have some simple questions.

commands like

```
git add
git commit
```

do they run inside of the directory/folders that the repo is in.

```
git status
git pull
git push
```

do I have to specify the git repo like https://github.com/mager1794/mygitrepo.git

I used to use tortoiseSVN so I used GUI based subversion for a while, but I heard its considered a good career skill to get good using git bash.

Comment: so when i right click and hit 'Git Bash Here' there i can just git add and git commit from there.  But for push and pull I need to specify the repo?  what about git status? do I have to specify the repo there as well

Comment: Please start by reading a tutorial, or a manual like [git-scm](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository). Then search for questions/answers that explain something specific if you don't understand something from the manual. If you still don't get it to work, ask your specific question.

Comment: And yes, the git commands should be executed in the repo directory. For `push` and `pull` you probably want to add a [remote](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) and use that as an alias for `https://github.com/mager1794/mygitrepo.git`

Comment: from my personal suggestion. Do not use GUI, Use git from command line then you will come to know all hidden feature...

Answer (score 0):

[`git add`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) and [`git commit`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) do run within any folder of your local git repo.
Please note the [difference between `git add` and `git add -A`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162511/6309) or [`git add -u`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2190440/6309).

[`git status`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) operates only in a local repo, a non-bare one, meaning one with a working tree checked out. (See ["concept of bare shared repository in git" on bare repos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24115534/6309))

[`git pull`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) and [git push](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) uses by default the remote named '`origin`': see "[Git Basics - Working with Remotes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)".
That avoids you to type the full url. See [`git remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote).

To test those commands, follow the [quick tutorial from GitHub](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1).