# How do you remove files from one and only one branch in git

Tags: git, git-branch

I want a branch to hold all the files from my master branch except for foo.txt and foo2.txt. How do I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to branch off from master.
Check out a new branch and remove the files you do not want.

```
git checkout master
```

Once in master:

```
git checkout -b new_branch

rm foo.txt
rm foo2.txt

git add -u
git commit -m "removed foo and foo2"
git push origin new_branch
```

Comment: Note that this *probably* won't work as written. You need the `-u` option provided to `git add` if you want it to stage the deletions. (http://stackoverflow.com/q/2190409)

Comment: Why do you need the -u?

Comment: git add -u will operate on the entire tree it will commit the deleted files