# How to stage all tracked modified files?

Tags: java, git, github, intellij-idea, terminal

Okay, This might be a silly question, but I am new to git, and getting confused a lot.

I have made some files on IntelliJ and now when I run `git status` in my IntelliJ terminal I get this:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)

  new file:  file x
  new file:  file y
  new file:  file z

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

 Modified: file x
 Modified: file y
 Modified: file z

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed) 

  file a 
  file b
```

I want to stage and commit the file x, file y, file z and do not want to stage the file a and file b.

I know `git add .` will stage all tracked and untracked files. Can something like `git add -u` do the job?

Note: There are a lot of files and I don't want to individually add them all.

Comment: `git add -u` does what you described. See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2190431/866021

Comment: Thanks !! I have one question tho:
"add -u will also stage deletions" --> what does that means?

Comment: This just means that running the `git add -u` command will also stage any files git was tracking that you've since deleted from the repo. Git will delete these files from the repo when you make the commit.

Comment: With reference to my example can you tell me what will git status look like after              
  git add -u . 
Let say along with the above files I have a deleted tracked file K.

Comment: It will look like this: `Modified: file x Modified: file y Modified: file z Deleted: file K`

Comment: Thanks, just one more thing? Can you give me a use case when to use git add -u . over git add . and a use case for git add. over the git add -u .

Comment: Sure - use `git add .` when you want Git to track all of the files in your current directory (even if they were not tracked before), and use `git add -u` when you want Git to stage all your changes to the files it's tracking across your entire repo (not just the current directory).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes - use the `git add -u` command when you want Git to stage all your modifications to the files it's currently tracking across your entire repository.

Answer (score 1):

> There are a lot many files and I don't want to individually add them all.

You can use git ignore and git will not add those files

```sh
### .gitignroe
<b full path>
```

**Important**: don't forget to add and commit your `.gitignore` file.

---

#### How to get a list of ignored files?

```sh
git check-ignore -v <path>
```

Comment: Single line command: `echo '<b file path>' >> .gitignore && git add .gitignore && git commit -m"Added gitignore"`