# Is it possible to move/rename files in Git and maintain their history?

Tags: git, rename, mv

I would like to rename/move a project subtree in Git moving it from

```
/project/xyz
```

to

```
/components/xyz
```

If I use a plain `git mv project components`, then all the commit history for the `xyz project` gets lost. Is there a way to move this such that the history is maintained?

Comment: about `git mv`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094269/whats-the-purpose-of-git-mv

Comment: I just want to note that I just tested moving files via the filesystem, and after committing (via intellij) I can then see the whole history (including history when it was at a different location) when viewing the history (again in intellij). I'm assuming intellij isn't doing anything particularly special to do that, so its nice to know that at very least the history can be traced.

Comment: For the rules followed by Git when detecting a directory rename, see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51601130/6309)

Comment: I wrote an answer here. I hope it works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828267/can-git-restructure-my-folders-without-losing-history/55339543#55339543

Comment: Git subtrees have "fake" histories anyway. When you break up a repository using `git-subtree`, Git gives the resulting subtree a fabricated history that is not the same as that of the project from which it broke away. I believe that git tries to determine all commits that involved the any of the files in the subtree, and it uses them to stitch together a  history. Also, these histories are rewritten every time you recombine and resplit the subtrees. Submodules however each have their own history separate from the parent project.

Answer (score 763, accepted):

Git detects renames rather than persisting the operation with the commit, so whether you use `git mv` or `mv` doesn't matter, as long as the move operation is committed separately from any changes to the file.

The `log` command takes a [`--follow`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---follow) argument that continues history before a rename operation, i.e., it searches for similar content using heuristics.

To lookup the full history, use the following command:

```
git log --follow ./path/to/file
```

Comment: It would be nice not to need the --follow but I guess this will have to do. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I suspect this is a performance consideration. If you don't need the full history, it will sure take longer time scanning the content. The easiest way is to setup an alias `git config alias.logf "log --follow"` and just write `git logf ./path/to/file`.

Comment: But which path do you specify, the old path or the new path? And if ti's the old path, how do you know to specify the old path?

Comment: You should just use the new path. It works the way that Git traverses back through history and switches to the old path, when a rename is detected.

Comment: Isn't there a way to set this in config? I couldn't find anything on docs or google.

Comment: @TroelsThomsen [this e-mail](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/217) by Linus Torvalds, linked from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10130671/833844), indicates that it's an intentional design choice of Git since it's allegedly much more powerful than tracking renames etc.

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading. Git does "detect renames," but very late in the game; the question is asking how you ensure Git tracks renames, and someone reading this can easily infer that Git detects them automatically for you and makes note of it. It does not. Git has no real handling of renames, and instead there are merge/log tools that attempt to figure out what happened - and rarely get it right. Linus has a mistaken but vehement argument as to why git should never just do it the right way and track renames explicitly. So, we're stuck here.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini Yep, Source Tree from Atlassian didn't detect a simple folder moving but rather saw it as a series of adds and deletes. Maybe upon comitting or even at push it might have detected it but I didn't take chances so I did the console git mv thing.

Comment: Note that "git log --follow" only works with individual files.

Comment: Important: if you rename a directory, for example during renaming of a Java package, be sure to execute two commits, first for the 'git mv {old} {new}' command, second for the updates of all Java files that reference the changed package directory. Otherwise git can't track the individual files even with the --follow parameter.

Comment: `git log --follow ./path/to/file` doesn't work for me, `git log --follow -- ./path/to/file` does. And the `--follow` is not unnecessary. -- `git v1.9.3`

Comment: I don't think it doesn't matter whether you use `git mv`or just `mv` in all cases. Simple renaming or moving seems to get detected quite fine, but for example moving files into a subsubfolder (yes, there are reason to do this) was not detected in my case.

Comment: @FlorianLoch As far as I can tell, all that is ever detected after a `mv` is the deletion. The adding of the renamed file must be done manually via `git add`, and afterwards git will detect the rename even if the files are not in the same directory.

Comment: I tried moving files and it git reported it as a delete and an add.  git mv reported these as renames.

Comment: So I'm moving from Subversion to Git and I want to clarify something. I get that Git doesn't add any file rename metadata. I get that `git log` will use heuristics to try to guess when a file moved. I get that if I move a file in Git I should commit the move before I modify the file to help Git follow history in the future. But I have a doubt about a real-world scenario: when I move something, I'm usually refactoring source code, so a .java file for example won't just move---at the very least the line indicating the package will change. Will this prevent 'git log' from following the history?

Comment: I see someone else asked the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3520023/421049 . But so far the answer isn't clear.

Comment: Though Linus probably makes very few mistakes, this does appears to be one.  Simply renaming a folder causes a massive delta to be uploaded to GitHub.  Which makes me cautious about renaming my folders...but that's a pretty big straight-jacket for a programmer.  Occasionally, I HAVE TO re-define the meaning of something, or change how things are categorized.  Linus: "In other words, I'm right. I'm always right, but sometimes I'm more right than other times. And dammit, when I say 'files don't matter', I'm really really Right(tm)." ...I have my doubts about that one.

Comment: @GarretWilson: `git log --follow` will follow the history if at least 50% of the file is still the same. You can change that percentage any time (with `-M`), because it is `git log` which follows similarities, not git on disk in general. (It is impossible to solve in general which rename+edit should be considered “same file”.)

Comment: @GabeHalsmer: Simply renaming a folder does not cause a massive delta (unless that includes other changes, such as references to the folder name in files). Of course, it is possible that GitHub _shows_ the renaming as a massive delta.

Comment: You can ensure correct rename detection by avoiding other changes to those files in a specific commit. If you rename => commit => edit them, git will be able to track this rename forever and for sure.

Comment: this also works with tig: `tig --follow filename` :)

Comment: This is what you are looking for. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190919-00/?p=102904

Comment: A long conversation going on but just a comment on one of the comments: If you rename a directory, there is no _massive_ delta involved. It actually means that a **tree object** will be **reused** and placed at a different location in the tree that makes up the following revision. Of course, the diff might be _huge_ (actually you would get a lot of renames in the diff, at least these days), but that doesn't mean that it's actually double the size of the renamed files that will be sent over to github with the push operation.

Comment: When looking at the logs in TortoiseGit in the Walk Behavior dropdown you need to select Follow renames.

Answer (score 208):

## No.

The short answer is **NO**. It is not possible to rename a file in Git and remember the history.  And it is a pain.

Rumor has it that `git log --follow` [`--find-copies-harder`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---find-copies-harder) will work, but it does not work for me, even if there are zero changes to the file contents, and the moves have been made with [`git mv`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv).

(Initially I used Eclipse to rename and update packages in one operation, which may have confused Git. But that is a very common thing to do. `--follow` does seem to work if only a `mv` is performed and then a `commit` and the `mv` is not too far.)

Linus says that you are supposed to understand the entire contents of a software project holistically, not needing to track individual files.  Well, sadly, my small brain cannot do that.

It is **really annoying** that so many people have mindlessly repeated the statement that Git automatically tracks moves.  They have wasted my time.  Git does no such thing. [By design(!) Git does not track moves at all.](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_does_Git_not_.22track.22_renames.3F)

My solution is to rename the files back to their original locations.  Change the software to fit the source control. With Git you just seem to need to "git" it right the first time.

Unfortunately, that breaks Eclipse, which seems to use `--follow`. [`git log --follow`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---follow) sometimes does not show the full history of files with complicated rename histories even though `git log` does. (I do not know why.)

(There are some too clever hacks that go back and recommit old work, but they are rather frightening. See GitHub-Gist: [emiller/git-mv-with-history](https://gist.github.com/emiller/6769886).)

In short: if [Subversion doing this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SVN-898#) is wrong, then Git doing this is also wrong - doing this isn't some (mis!)feature, **it's a mistake.**

Comment: I believe you are correct.  I was just trying to use php-cs-fixer to reformat the source for my Laravel 5 project but it insists on changing the capitalization of the namespace clauses to match the lowercase value of the app folder.  But namespaces (or composer autoloads) only work with CamelCase.  I need to change the capitalization of the folder to App but this causes my changes to be lost.  This is the most trivial of examples, but shows how the git heuristic is not able to follow even the simplest of name changes (--follow and --find-copies-harder should be the rule, not the exception).

Comment: Is this still true ? That's more reason for me to stay with tfs for now, keeping the history of a moved/renamed file is a must in a large project.

Comment: @Cesar If by "remember the history", he means "follow renames when viewing log" 
 (which is the only useful thing we should care about), then this was *never* true! Git does not "record" renames, but tools can easily detect them and present us with renames and moves. If "it does not work" for someone, he/she should change the tools he/she is using. There are lots of wonderful [Git GUIs](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis) that have this ability.

Comment: The short answer is Yes. Git current version supports "git log --follow" as well. and I agree with @MohammadDehghan

Comment: @Cesar now you have another opcion, see git-filter-repo answers below, by Parag Bangad and Pugsley.

Comment: `git log --follow` works for me, but only if the `git mv` moves the file to something untracked. If you try to do `rm a.txt && git mv b.txt a.txt` then b.txt's history will be destroyed. You have to first `git rm a.txt` then commit, then `git mv b.txt a.txt` if you want `git log --follow` to work.

Comment: For me it works what @yoyo has written in the comment to another answer of this question: "It appears that this requires you to commit just the rename before you start modifying the file. If you move the file (in the shell) and then change it, all bets are off". => After renaming commit it and only then start to modify it.
(P.S.: I've done this via Eclipse plugin egit)

Comment: I think I'm going to start asking some developers to explicitly enumerate the file moves in a PR if and when they take place. I agree with @Turntable source file provenance with links to issue numbers, Jira tickets, commit messages, authors, etc is useful stuff to track. It doesn't explain the project holistically from a logical perspective but definitely reveals the human side of development and what clues can be gleaned from such information.

Comment: Another example of [this stupid content tracker's](https://git-scm.com/docs/git) inability to preserve history across file renames can be found [here](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/darcs-evaluation#file-renames).

Comment: While this answer may have had merit a long time ago, modern git toolchain seems very good at tracking renames and moves, even detecting "soft renames" as typically happens when you do a package refactor in a Java IDE resulting in a simultaneous file move and a change to the "package" line in the .java file.  In my experience this "mostly" works, although you should up the "soft rename limit" for sizable projects.

Answer (score 126):

It is *possible* to rename a file and keep the history intact, although it causes the file to be renamed throughout the entire history of the repository. This is probably only for the obsessive git-log-lovers, and has some serious implications, including these:

- You could be rewriting a shared history, which is the most important DON'T while using Git. If someone else has cloned the repository, you'll break it doing this. They will have to re-clone to avoid headaches. This might be OK if the rename is important enough, but you'll need to consider this carefully -- you might end up upsetting an entire opensource community!
- If you've referenced the file using it's old name earlier in the repository history, you're effectively breaking earlier versions. To remedy this, you'll have to do a bit more hoop jumping. It's not impossible, just tedious and possibly not worth it.

Now, since you're still with me, you're a probably solo developer renaming a completely isolated file. Let's move a file using `filter-tree`!

Assume you're going to move a file `old` into a folder `dir` and give it the name `new`

This could be done with `git mv old dir/new && git add -u dir/new`, but that breaks history.

Instead:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'if [ -f old ]; then mkdir dir && mv old dir/new; fi' HEAD
```

will *redo* every commit in the branch, executing the command in the ticks for each iteration. Plenty of stuff can go wrong when you do this. I normally test to see if the file is present (otherwise it's not there yet to move) and then perform the necessary steps to shoehorn the tree to my liking. Here you might sed through files to alter references to the file and so on. Knock yourself out! :)

When completed, the file is moved and the log is intact. You feel like a ninja pirate.

Also; The mkdir dir is only necessary if you move the file to a new folder, of course. The *if* will avoid the creation of this folder earlier in history than your file exists.

Comment: As an obsessive git-log-lover, I wouldn't go for this. The files weren't named that at those points in time, hence history reflects a never-existent situation. Who knows what tests might break in the past! The risk of breaking earlier versions is in pretty much every case not worth it.

Comment: @Vincent You're absolutely right, and I tried to be as clear as I could about the unlikeliness of this solution being appropriate. I also think we're talking about two meanings of the word "history" in this case, I appreciate both.

Comment: I find there are situations where one might need this. Say I developed something in my own personal branch, which I now want to merge upstream. But I discover, the filename isn't apropriate, so I change it for my whole personal branch. In that way I can keep a clean proper history and have the correct name from the beginning.

Comment: @user2291758 that's my use case. These more powerful git commands are dangerous but that doesn't mean they don't have very compelling use cases if you know what you're doing!

Comment: if possible, using the `--index-filter` for renames will be much faster as the tree won't have to be checked out and back in on every commit. `--index-filter` acts directly on each commit index.

Comment: I don't understand how is the mv command supposed to work here. Shouldn't it be git mv?

Comment: @MattiJokipii: The `mv`command is used to move the file before each commit throughout the repository's history, so using a normal unix `mv` is the correct one. I'm not even sure what would happen if you use a `git mv`. If you're using windows, you should use the `move` command.

Comment: Nice solution; I would use `[-f old] && mkdir -p dir && mv old dir/new` to get rid of the conditional structure and avoid failures if the directory already exists. So the command is run once for each commit but only has any effect the first time? Or is the entire tree rebuilt for each commit? I assume this is safe to perform with multiple files using a wildcard as well

Answer (score 50):

```
git log --follow [file]
```

will show you the history through renames.

Comment: It appears that this requires you to commit just the rename before you start modifying the file. If you move the file (in the shell) and then change it, all bets are off.

Comment: @yoyo: that's because git doesn't track renames, it detects them. A `git mv` basically does a `git rm && git add`. There are options like `-M90` / `--find-renames=90` to consider a file to be renamed when it's 90% identical.

Answer (score 33):

I do:

```
git mv {old} {new}
git add -u {new}
```

Comment: The -u doesn't seem to do anything for me, is it suppose to update the history?

Comment: Perhaps you want the behavior of `-A` instead? Again, see here: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add

Comment: It does add the files, however it doesn't update the history so that 'git log file name' shows the full history. It only shows the full history if you use the --follow option still.

Comment: I did a complicated refactor that moved an include directory (using mv, not git mv) and then changed lots of #include paths within the renamed files.  git could not find enough similarity to track the history.  But git add -u was just the thing I needed.  git status now indicates "renamed" where before it showed "deleted" and "new file".

Comment: This answer may be tangentially related to the question, but doesn't bother to describe how.  From what I can tell, `git add -u` doesn't have any affect if you have [already used `git mv` (or `git rm`)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3639399/86967).  The OP already noted that `git mv` doesn't solve their problem.  Apparently, though, this answer has helped some people who were wanting to improve the output of `git status`.

Comment: There are lots of questions on SO that address the purpose of `git add -u`.  The Git docs tend to be unhelpful, and are the last place I would want to look.  Here's one post showing `git add -u` in action: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2117202.

Comment: In my case too, `git add -u` didn't change anything. It showed that the file was renamed before using `git add -u`, and showed that the file was renamed after using `git -add -u`.

Comment: This did not update the full history for me.

Answer (score 24):

> I would like to rename/move a project subtree in Git moving it from
>
> ```
> /project/xyz
> ```
>
> to
>
> /components/xyz
>
> If I use a plain `git mv project components`, then all the commit history for the `xyz` project gets lost.

No (8 years later, Git 2.19, Q3 2018), because Git will **detect the directory rename**, and this is now better documented.

See [commit b00bf1c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b00bf1c9a8dd5009d5102aef7af9e2b886b1e5ad), [commit 1634688](https://github.com/git/git/commit/16346883ab0f548aa57ed5617caacc66c0a25bea), [commit 0661e49](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0661e49aeb842a29f2ebbd7b005ec5824c2b87e1), [commit 4d34dff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d34dffbdd2226034df9d7612f1e221b7143fc6a), [commit 983f464](https://github.com/git/git/commit/983f464fcbab700a2cac6011fa6941dab839548d), [commit c840e1a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c840e1af09fcf9bb4420a504820314b67fbe18d2), [commit 9929430](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9929430c32f8754de559e00fba65fd978ecd05da) (27 Jun 2018), and [commit d4e8062](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d4e80629ff480cbddd8c1ac7e7cfb86d58978514), [commit 5dacd4a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5dacd4abdd3ce120b7c206b3a7184f9e0c83781a) (25 Jun 2018) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0ce5a69](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0ce5a698c6f775c2cc18de9eb62d558b1b85d752), 24 Jul 2018)</sup>

That is now explained in [`Documentation/technical/directory-rename-detection.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4d34dffbdd2226034df9d7612f1e221b7143fc6a/Documentation/technical/directory-rename-detection.txt):

Example:

> When all of `x/a`, `x/b` and `x/c` have moved to `z/a`, `z/b` and `z/c`, it is likely that `x/d` added in the meantime would also want to move to `z/d` by
>   taking the hint that the entire directory '`x`' moved to '`z`'.

But they are many other cases, like:

> one side of history renames `x -> z`, and the other renames some file to
>   `x/e`, causing the need for the merge to do a transitive rename.

To simplify directory rename detection, those rules are enforced by Git:

a couple basic rules limit when
directory rename detection applies:

> 1. If a given directory still exists on both sides of a merge, we do not consider it to have been renamed.
> 2. If a subset of to-be-renamed files have a file or directory in the way (or would be in the way of each other), "turn off" the directory rename for those specific sub-paths and report the conflict to the user.
> 3. If the other side of history did a directory rename to a path that your side of history renamed away, then ignore that particular rename from the other side of history for any implicit directory renames (but warn the user).

You can see *a lot* of tests in [`t/t6043-merge-rename-directories.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4d34dffbdd2226034df9d7612f1e221b7143fc6a/t/t6043-merge-rename-directories.sh), which also point out that:

> - a) If renames split a directory into two or more others, the directory with the most renames, "wins".
> - b) Avoid directory-rename-detection for a path, if that path is the source of a rename on either side of a merge.
> - c) Only apply implicit directory renames to directories if the other side
>     of history is the one doing the renaming.

Answer (score 18):

## Yes

1. You convert the commit history of files into email patches using `git log --pretty=email`
2. You reorganize these files in new directories and rename them
3. You convert back these files (emails) to Git commits to keep the history using [`git am`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-am).

#### Limitation

- Tags and branches are not kept
- History is cut on path file rename (directory rename)

---

## Step by step explanation with examples

#### 1. Extract history in email format

Example: Extract history of `file3`, `file4` and `file5`

```
my_repo
├── dirA
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2
├── dirB            ^
│   ├── subdir      | To be moved
│   │   ├── file3   | with history
│   │   └── file4   | 
│   └── file5       v
└── dirC
    ├── file6
    └── file7
```

Set/clean the destination

```
export historydir=/tmp/mail/dir       # Absolute path
rm -rf "$historydir"    # Caution when cleaning the folder
```

Extract history of each file in email format

```
cd my_repo/dirB
find -name .git -prune -o -type d -o -exec bash -c 'mkdir -p "$historydir/${0%/*}" && git log --pretty=email -p --stat --reverse --full-index --binary -- "$0" > "$historydir/$0"' {} ';'
```

Unfortunately option `--follow` or `--find-copies-harder` cannot be combined with `--reverse`. This is why history is cut when file is renamed (or when a parent directory is renamed).

Temporary history in email format:

```
/tmp/mail/dir
    ├── subdir
    │   ├── file3
    │   └── file4
    └── file5
```

[Dan Bonachea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3528321) suggests to invert the loops of the git log generation command in this first step: rather than running git log once per file, run it exactly once with a list of files on the command line and generate a single unified log. This way commits that modify multiple files remain a single commit in the result, and all the new commits maintain their original relative order. Note this also requires changes in second step below when rewriting filenames in the (now unified) log.

---

#### 2. Reorganize file tree and update filenames

Suppose you want to move these three files in this other repo (can be the same repo).

```
my_other_repo
├── dirF
│   ├── file55
│   └── file56
├── dirB              # New tree
│   ├── dirB1         # from subdir
│   │   ├── file33    # from file3
│   │   └── file44    # from file4
│   └── dirB2         # new dir
│        └── file5    # from file5
└── dirH
    └── file77
```

Therefore reorganize your files:

```
cd /tmp/mail/dir
mkdir -p dirB/dirB1
mv subdir/file3 dirB/dirB1/file33
mv subdir/file4 dirB/dirB1/file44
mkdir -p dirB/dirB2
mv file5 dirB/dirB2
```

Your temporary history is now:

```
/tmp/mail/dir
    └── dirB
        ├── dirB1
        │   ├── file33
        │   └── file44
        └── dirB2
             └── file5
```

Change also filenames within the history:

```
cd "$historydir"
find * -type f -exec bash -c 'sed "/^diff --git a\|^--- a\|^+++ b/s:\( [ab]\)/[^ ]*:\1/$0:g" -i "$0"' {} ';'
```

---

#### 3. Apply new history

Your other repo is:

```
my_other_repo
├── dirF
│   ├── file55
│   └── file56
└── dirH
    └── file77
```

Apply commits from temporary history files:

```
cd my_other_repo
find "$historydir" -type f -exec cat {} + | git am --committer-date-is-author-date
```

`--committer-date-is-author-date` preserves the original commit time-stamps ([Dan Bonachea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3528321)'s comment).

Your other repo is now:

```
my_other_repo
├── dirF
│   ├── file55
│   └── file56
├── dirB
│   ├── dirB1
│   │   ├── file33
│   │   └── file44
│   └── dirB2
│        └── file5
└── dirH
    └── file77
```

Use `git status` to see amount of commits ready to be pushed :-)

---

#### Extra trick: Check renamed/moved files within your repo

To list the files having been renamed:

```
find -name .git -prune -o -exec git log --pretty=tformat:'' --numstat --follow {} ';' | grep '=>'
```

More customizations: You can complete the command `git log` using options `--find-copies-harder` or `--reverse`. You can also remove the first two columns using `cut -f3-` and grepping complete pattern `'{.* => .*}'`.

```
find -name .git -prune -o -exec git log --pretty=tformat:'' --numstat --follow --find-copies-harder --reverse {} ';' | cut -f3- | grep '{.* => .*}'
```

Comment: BEWARE: This technique splits commits that change 2 or more files into separate fragmented-commits, and furthermore scrambles their order by sorting on filename (so the fragments of one original commit do not appear adjacent in linear history). The resulting history is therefore only "correct" on a file-by-file basis. If you are moving more than one file, then NONE of the new commits in the resulting history represent a consistent snapshot of the moved files that ever existed in the history of the original repo.

Comment: Hi @DanBonachea. Thank you for your interesting feedback. I have successfully migrated some repos containing several files using this technique (even with renamed files and files moved across directories). What do you suggest to change in this answer. Do you think we should add an WARNING banner at the top of this answer explaining the limitations of this technique? Cheers

Comment: I adapted this technique to avoid the problem by inverting the loops of the git log generation command in step 1. Ie. rather than running git log once per file, run it exactly once with a list of files on the command line and generate a single unified log. This way commits that modify 2 or more files remain a single commit in the result, and all the new commits maintain their original relative order. Note this also requires changes in step 2 when rewriting filenames in the (now unified) log.
I also used git am --committer-date-is-author-date  to preserve the original commit timestamps.

Comment: Thank you for your experimentation and sharing. I have updated a bit the answer for other readers. However I have took time to test your processing. Please feel free to edit this answer if you want to provide examples of command lines. Cheers ;)

Answer (score 15):

I have faced the issue *"Renaming the folder without loosing history"*. To fix it, run:

```sh
$ git mv oldfolder temp && git mv temp newfolder
$ git commit
$ git push
```

Comment: This should be marked the correct answer.  Totally worked for me to move a file from one folder to another within the same repo.  I didn't even have to do the 'temp' thing.  git mv olddir/file newdir/file worked for me.

Comment: And all history is saved.

Comment: Why is this better than `git mv oldfolder newfolder`?

Comment: Wanted to note that this also works with files. Just did a rename and it persisted the history using @EliezerBerlin's response above.

Answer (score 14):

I followed this multi-step process to move code to the parent directory and retained history.

Step 0: Created a branch 'history' from 'master' for safekeeping

Step 1: Used [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) tool to rewrite history. This command below moved folder 'FolderwithContentOfInterest' to one level up and modified the relevant commit history

```
git filter-repo --path-rename ParentFolder/FolderwithContentOfInterest/:FolderwithContentOfInterest/ --force
```

Step 2: By this time the GitHub repository lost its remote repository path. Added remote reference

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:MyCompany/MyRepo.git
```

Step 3: Pull information on repository

```
git pull
```

Step 4: Connect the local lost branch with the origin branch

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/history history
```

Step 5: Address merge conflict for the folder structure if prompted

Step 6: *Push*!!

```
git push
```

Note: The modified history and moved folder appear to already be committed. `enter code here`

Done. Code moves to the parent / desired directory keeping history intact!

Comment: This should be way higher in the list of answers, as of 2020 filter-repo is the way to go for this kind of operations.

Answer (score 12):

To rename a directory or file (I don't know much about complex cases, so there might be some caveats):

```
git filter-repo --path-rename OLD_NAME:NEW_NAME
```

To rename a directory in files that mention it (it's possible to use callbacks, but I don't know how):

```
git filter-repo --replace-text expressions.txt
```

`expressions.txt` is a file filled with lines like `literal:OLD_NAME==>NEW_NAME` (it's possible to use Python's RE with `regex:` or glob with `glob:`).

To rename a directory in messages of commits:

```
git-filter-repo --message-callback 'return message.replace(b"OLD_NAME", b"NEW_NAME")'
```

Python's regular expressions are also supported, but they must be written in Python, manually.

If the repository is original, without remote, you will have to add `--force` to force a rewrite. (You may want to create a backup of your repository before doing this.)

If you do not want to preserve refs (they will be displayed in the branch history of Git GUI), you will have to add `--replace-refs delete-no-add`.

Comment: `git: 'filter-repo' is not a git command. See 'git --help'`

Comment: @alper This command works! But filter-repo is not a standard command in Git. You need to install it before you can use it. You can find instructions how to download and how to install here https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo

Answer (score 7):

Simply **move the file** and stage with:

```
git add .
```

Before commit you can check the status:

```
git status
```

That will show:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        renamed:    old-folder/file.txt -> new-folder/file.txt
```

I tested with Git version 2.26.1.

Extracted from [GitHub Help Page](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-files-in-a-repository/moving-a-file-to-a-new-location-using-the-command-line).

Answer (score 4):

While the core of Git, the Git plumbing doesn't keep track of renames, the history you display with the Git log "porcelain" can detect them if you like.

For a given `git log` use the -M option:

> git log -p -M

*With a current version of Git.*

This works for other commands like `git diff` as well.

There are options to make the comparisons more or less rigorous. If you rename a file without making significant changes to the file at the same time it makes it easier for Git log and friends to detect the rename. For this reason some people rename files in one commit and change them in another.

There's a cost in CPU use whenever you ask Git to find where files have been renamed, so whether you use it or not, and when, is up to you.

If you would like to always have your history reported with rename detection in a particular repository you can use:

> git config diff.renames 1

Files moving from one directory to another *is* detected. Here's an example:

```
commit c3ee8dfb01e357eba1ab18003be1490a46325992
Author: John S. Gruber <JohnSGruber@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Feb 22 22:20:19 2017 -0500

    test rename again

diff --git a/yyy/power.py b/zzz/power.py
similarity index 100%
rename from yyy/power.py
rename to zzz/power.py

commit ae181377154eca800832087500c258a20c95d1c3
Author: John S. Gruber <JohnSGruber@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Feb 22 22:19:17 2017 -0500

    rename test

diff --git a/power.py b/yyy/power.py
similarity index 100%
rename from power.py
rename to yyy/power.py
```

Please note that this works whenever you are using diff, not just with `git log`. For example:

```
$ git diff HEAD c3ee8df
diff --git a/power.py b/zzz/power.py
similarity index 100%
rename from power.py
rename to zzz/power.py
```

As a trial I made a small change in one file in a feature branch and committed it and then in the master branch I renamed the file, committed, and then made a small change in another part of the file and committed that. When I went to feature branch and merged from master the merge renamed the file and merged the changes. Here's the output from the merge:

```
 $ git merge -v master
 Auto-merging single
 Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
  one => single | 4 ++++
  1 file changed, 4 insertions(+)
  rename one => single (67%)
```

The result was a working directory with the file renamed and both text changes made. So it's possible for Git to do the right thing despite the fact that it doesn't explicitly track renames.

<sub>This is an late answer to an old question so the other answers may have been correct for the Git version at the time.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

First create a standalone commit with just a rename.

Then any eventual changes to the file content put in the separate commit.

Comment: YES! This is the way to go.  Do not mix rename/mv with *ANY* other changes to the codebase

Comment: @WestCoastProjects As long as with the changes the file still has > 50 % similarity, the rename should still be detected by git using default settings.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I moved two files from a 'resources' directory into 'src/main/resources'. As following code shows they appeared as 'deleted'.

However, after I added the relocated files into staging area and then added the deleted ones, the system recognized them as "renamed".

When I check the history of both files, it was intact and their permanent links were still working. So, everything works as we might have hoped.

```
myaddress (master *)$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        deleted:    resources/myaddress-schemas.sql
        deleted:    resources/select-sangdo-ro-60.sql

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .gitignore
        pom.xml
        src/

myaddress (master *)$ git add src/main/resources/*.sql
myaddress (master *+)$ git add `git ls-files --deleted`

myaddress (master +)$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        renamed:    resources/myaddress-schemas.sql -> src/main/resources/myaddress-schemas.sql
        renamed:    resources/select-sangdo-ro-60.sql -> src/main/resources/select-sangdo-ro-60.sql

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .gitignore
        pom.xml
        src/main/java/
        src/main/webapp/

myaddress (master +)$
myaddress (master +)$ git commit -m "two resource files moved to src/main"
[master 0832839] two resource files moved to src/main
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename {resources => src/main/resources}/myaddress-schemas.sql (100%)
 rename {resources => src/main/resources}/select-sangdo-ro-60.sql (100%)
myaddress (master)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes
you can:

1. move the file => commit
2. rename the file => commit
   (dont move and rename in the same commit)
   now the file will keep their git history