# See what happend to files in Github trees API

Tags: github, github-api

Through the github API i'm listing all the files and folders of a certain commit, like so:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/git/trees/:sha?recursive=1
```

That gives me a list like this:

```
{
  "sha": "9fb037999f264ba9a7fc6274d15fa3ae2ab98312",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/trees/9fb037999f264ba9a7fc6274d15fa3ae2ab98312",
  "tree": [
    {
      "path": "file.rb",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "size": 30,
      "sha": "44b4fc6d56897b048c772eb4087f854f46256132",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/blobs/44b4fc6d56897b048c772eb4087f854f46256132"
    },
    {
      "path": "subdir",
      "mode": "040000",
      "type": "tree",
      "sha": "f484d249c660418515fb01c2b9662073663c242e",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/blobs/f484d249c660418515fb01c2b9662073663c242e"
    },
    {
      "path": "exec_file",
      "mode": "100755",
      "type": "blob",
      "size": 75,
      "sha": "45b983be36b73c0788dc9cbcb76cbb80fc7bb057",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/blobs/45b983be36b73c0788dc9cbcb76cbb80fc7bb057"
    }
  ]
}
```

But how can i tell what happend to the file? Like, how can i tell if it got editted in this commit, or renamed or deleted etc? I can't seem to figure out how to get that info.

How can i get that info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The edits, rename or deletion are base on the history found in git log.
So the tree API alone isn't enough for GitHub to provide that information: you need to extract it from the log associated to a given tree or file.

You can use the [API for commits](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/) in order to list commits for a given file, or even compare two commits together, which would give you the detail in term of edit.

```
"files": [
    {
      "sha": "6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e",
      "filename": "file1.txt",
      "status": "added",
      "additions": 103,
      "deletions": 21,
      "changes": 124,
      "blob_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/blob/6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e/file1.txt",
      "raw_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/raw/6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e/file1.txt",
      "patch": "@@ -132,7 +132,7 @@ module Test @@ -1000,7 +1000,7 @@ module Test"
    }
  ]
```

But I don't think you can easily see renames through the API alone.
You would have to clone the repo and to a [`git log -M --summary`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4402945/6309) in order to see those moves/renames.