# SVN-to-git: How can I preserve history for files moved in SVN repo when migrating to git?

Tags: git, svn, migration, git-svn

I have a situation similar to the following:

- SVN Revision 1

  - FolderA/FileA.ext

('svn move' used to move folder underneath a new folder)

- SVN Revision 2

  - NewParent/FolderA/FileA.ext

Using SVN, I can verify the history is present for both revisions.

When I use 'git svn clone', the target folder contains both FolderA/FileA.ext and NewParent/FolderA/FileA.ext, and there is no history link between them.

How can I preserve the history link and only end up with the newer folder structure? I only need to migrate once (no link to SVN repo is needed).

Comment: Alternatively, how can I take NewParent/FolderA/FileA.ext and apply its history to FolderA/FileA.ext?

Answer (score 2):

First, check that the history is indeed lost, by checking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2314757/6309) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4402945/6309):

```
git log --follow -- NewParent/FolderA/FileA.ext
# or
git log -M --summary -- NewParent/FolderA/FileA.ext
```

If the link seems lost, you can try convert your svn repo using [subgit](http://subgit.com/), which does more work to keep all the svn information identical in the new git repo (as [its author explains here](http://episodes.gitminutes.com/2013/09/gitminutes-22-alexander-kitaev-about.html)).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did indeed try both of your suggestions. The 'git log' verified the files' histories are not linked. I was also unsuccessful in bending subgit to my will (and I am not sure we are under the ten developer limit for the free version). I am trying a "branch" argument trick for 'git svn clone', and it seemed viable on the subset I tried. Unfortunately, I had to leave and don't have access until Monday.