# In Git how can I show files changed with type of change

Tags: git, rename, history, git-log

How do I use git log to show:

```
commit <hash id>
Author: <author info>
Date: <date info>

<commit message>

<files changed>
```

in the files changed section I also want to know how the file was changed.
Either created, deleted, renamed, or modified.

`git log -M --summary` Shows created, deleted, or renamed type with file name next to the change. The result is missing modified files.

`git log --name-only` Shows all files changed, but now how they are changed

`git log -p` Shows all the changes in a file.

But how can I do something like `git log -M --summary` where it also shows if a file was modified?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393527/why-might-git-log-not-show-history-for-a-moved-file-and-what-can-i-do-about-it) question addresses showing files that are added or moved.

Comment: Perhaps you want `--name-status`? Note that `-M` by itself simply enables rename detection, which you can also do by setting your personal (`--global`) Git configuration (`git config --global diff.renames true`). Rename detection is now on by default in Git version 2.9 and higher. (You might also like `git log --raw`, which used to be known as `git whatchanged`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if that's what you want, but I once used the flag `--name-status` for something similar (not sure if it has changed since then). Here's the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---name-status)