# Renaming files in git

Tags: git

I have two files checked into GitHub:

1. index.html
2. backup.html

Now I want to rename `backup.html` into `index.html` and vice versa. I don't really care about maintaining the change history for each file. How do I do this in Git?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will contain the history:

```
git mv backup.html backup2.html
git mv index.html backup.html
git mv backup2.html index.html
```

Without history just rename the file to your liking on your file system.

Comment: Note that `git mv` doesn't do much of anything special. This is more or less a shortcut for Charles Bailey's answer.

Comment: git mv does preserve history of the renamed files.

Comment: Right but so does Charles Bailey's answer. It's not like svn where it's possible to preserve the history, or not. Git always preserves history when possible.

Comment: @MatrixFrog I've [found out the hard way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351091/git-and-binary-files-history) this ain't so [pretty as it should](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314652/is-it-possible-to-move-rename-files-in-git-and-maintain-their-history). The history might be preserved somewhere, but you can't find it in any easy way with binaries or in some specific cases. It's not just "when possible" - [following a file history is a highly underlooked feature by git developers (namely Linus)](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/git-version-control/07oWjHiQTtg).

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do anything special as you are not adding any new paths to be tracked.

You can just move the files around and use `git add` to update their contents.

```
mv index.html tmpname
mv backup.html index.html
mv tmpname backup.html
```

then:

```
git add index.html backup.html
```

or:

```
git add -u
```

or:

```
git commit -a -m "swap backup.html and index.html"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `git mv` and move the first file to a temporary name, then the second to the first and finally the temporary file to the second.