# How to find all renames in all commits on git?

Tags: git

I'm lost in a repo maze with a bunch of files that were readded while their older version was renamed because of a not-so-good rebase that was made.

Anyway, I want to list all the files that at some point were renamed, that is, list all renamed files from all commits.

Comment: `git log --follow`

from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743739/how-to-really-show-logs-of-renamed-files-with-git)

Comment: sorry, no, I want to list *all* files that were changed in all commits, `--follow` only works for a single file.

Comment: It sounds like you are in an icky situation. Are you able to use `git reflog` (or a branch, or something) prior to the rebase and redo your commits from there so you aren't in this position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would this suffice?

`git whatchanged -M5 --summary | grep rename | grep '=>'`

Here is a modified version which will do renamed and deleted files:

`git whatchanged -M5 --summary | grep -E 'rename.*=>|delete mode'`

This will give you all renames from the HEAD of your current branch and it's ancestry including merged parents up to the very first commit.  The -M5 will have files that are similar by 50% or more reported as a rename; this may be to low of a percentage but you can change it (The 5 is read as .5, or 50% so you could change it to M8 for 80%).  Be warned, it will take a long time if there are a lot of commits.

I suggest you limit the range of commits such as:

`git whatchanged -M5 --summary <commit-id>..HEAD | grep rename | grep '=>'`

As far as I can tell you will need to start with a commit, I am not sure how you could get a comprehensive list of renamed files across all branches and tags at once.  If you have divergent branches you want to check, or branches with independent commit histories in a single repo, you will need to run the suggested command on each branch.

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks. Can you update your answer to include deleted files as well?

Comment: @Roberto Sure, I added a version that will show which files were deleted as well.

Comment: `--summary` was clipping the file names for me. I used this command instead:
`git whatchanged -M5 <commit-hash>..HEAD | grep R100`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get that info from the logs using [--diff-filter](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203) option. The filter for renamed files is **R**, and **D** for deleted files.

Renamed files:

```
git log --summary --pretty='format:' --diff-filter=R
```

Deleted files:

```
git log --summary --pretty='format:' --diff-filter=D
```

Renamed + deleted files:

```
git log --summary --pretty='format:' --diff-filter=RD
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Background

It's important to note that renames work in git are special.

Due to the fundamental nature of how git works, renames are not recorded into the version control system. They are reconstructed after the fact, in the same way that diff hunks are, by comparing the binary content of files between revisions.

This means that `file_a` and `file_b`, are considered "renamed" between two revisions if `file_a` is deleted, `file_a` is added and they are "similar" enough. (I believe the default is 50%). Note that this means finding renames requires a bit more computation.

It also means that renames can often only be detected by walking the entire range of revisions. Unless, the rename is basically the only change in the range, say `HEAD` and `HEAD~100`, in such case it can also be detected using `git diff --name-status --diff-filter=R`.

#### How to list all renames in current branch

You can't use `git-rev-list` for this, you need to use `git-log`.

```bash
git log --name-status -M90%\
 --diff-filter=R --pretty=format: |
  sed\
  -e '/^$/{N;s@^\n$@@}'\
  -e 's@\(^\n\{0,1\}\)R[0-9]\{3\}\t@\1@'
```

- `--name-status`, `--pretty=format:` just display the old name `<tab>` new name, no subject etc. of regular `git-log`.
- `-M90%`, how similar counts as difference `-M100%` for identical (only renamed).
- `--diff-filter=R`, only show renames
- `sed` massage the output

  - `-e '/^$/{N;s@^\n$@@}'` strip output from commits with no renames (2x+ `\n`)
  - `-e 's@\(^\n\{0,1\}\)R[0-9]\{3\}\t@\1@'`, massage the output to *old_name* `<tab>` *new_name*

#### Example

Running in the Git projects repository.

```bash
$ git log --name-status -M100%\
 --diff-filter=R --pretty=format: \
  v2.38.0..v2.39.0 |
  sed\
  -e '/^$/{N;s@^\n$@@}'\
  -e 's@\(^\n\{0,1\}\)R[0-9]\{3\}\t@\1@' |
  cat -A
fuzz-commit-graph.c^Ioss-fuzz/fuzz-commit-graph.c$
fuzz-pack-headers.c^Ioss-fuzz/fuzz-pack-headers.c$
fuzz-pack-idx.c^Ioss-fuzz/fuzz-pack-idx.c$
```

you can see that a couple of files were moved to `oss-fuzz/` directory, between git versions `2.38.0` and `2.39.0`.