# Git merge of moved files

Tags: git, github

I forked a repo and changed the file A. Now file A in the upstream repo has moved to a sub directory. I am trying to merge the upstream repo to my fork.

Git thinks that file A was deleted in its original location and a new one was created in the new sub directory (This could also be because, of the way they moved the file upstream).

I want to get my modifications into this file in the new location with least possible repercussions, w.r.t history of commits and stuff. Can anyone please help me out with ways to achieve this?

Comment: Do you get conflicts when merging? Usually Git is clever enough to figure out that a file was moved. What happens if you simply run `git merge origin/master` (or whatever your upstream branch is called)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Git always detects renames "after the fact", by comparing the two trees in question (or one tree and the index, for cases that don't include `git merge` itself).  (Linus Torvalds considers this a feature; see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5743739/1256452) for instance.)

In any case, `git merge` will run git's internal diff with merge detection enabled and the default similarity-index of 50%, unless you configure it otherwise.<sup>1</sup>  Similarly, `git diff` has some defaults which are also configurable.  If you run `git diff --find-renames -M50%` manually between your merge-base and the upstream, you're probably fine (but see footnote 1 about configuring).

If git *does not* detect the rename, you may need to adjust the rename detection thresholds and/or increase the number of files that git should consider.  The first of these is the `rename-threshold` value in the `-X` options (`rename-threshold` first appeared in git 1.7.4).  See [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) for details.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can set `merge.renameLimit` to the number of files to consider in terms of rename detection.  If you do not set it, the current default is 1000 files (but the default has changed over time).  Also, if you do not set it, merge uses `diff.renameLimit`, so you can set just the second of these, and have both diff and merge use both values.

The way file rename detection works is a bit complex, but simple enough to describe by example.  Suppose that git is comparing commit `12345` with commit `67890`, and in `12345` there are files with pathnames `A`, `B/C`, and `D`; but in `67890` there are pathnames `B/gronk`, `B/C`, and `D`.  This means path `A` is gone but new path `B/gronk` has appeared.  Git will then remember such paths (up to the rename limit value), and will compare the contents of `12345:A` with the contents of `67890:B/gronk`.  If the files are "sufficiently similar", git will declare that `12345:A` was renamed to `67890:B/gronk`.

I'm not sure precisely how git decides that a file is 50%, or 75%, or whatever, similar/different.  I have seen that similarity index is based on "chunks" rather than lines (even though the usual diff output is line-oriented), though.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use `git mv` and not just `mv` to move the file.

Since `git` takes a snapshot of the content it does not care about the filename (which is stored in an idx file as metadata).

If you simply move the file, git will not "understand" that you want to move it and will treat it as a new file.

You need to revert your changes and then use:

```
git mv <old path> <new path>
```

Now in git status you will see the move of the file and not the deletion of one and the creation of a new one.

Comment: This is incorrect, or at least incomplete: git discovers renames "after the fact" when comparing two trees, or comparing a tree and the index, based on the flags supplied to its internal diff code.  The `git status` command always sets "check for renames" but `git diff` and `git show` use `-M`, `--find-renames`, `--no-renames`, and your config settings (`diff.renames` and `diff.renamelimit`) to control the rename-detection machinery.  If you've already renamed a file, then `git rm --cached` the old path and `git add` the new path, you get the same effect as if you had used `git mv`.

Comment: I haven't manually moved the file. I am trying to merge the upstream repo with mine. It is moved in the upstream repo.