# Can I git diff a file which name has changed?

Tags: git, diff

When a file name or path changes, `git status` doesn't tell me that there is a modified file, it tells me that there is a deleted file and a created file. `git diff` shows me all the content of the previous version of the file, and doesn't show me the new content (since it's a new file).

Is it possible to see the changes in a file which name or path has changed?

Comment: To avoid two seperate git status messages, you can use `git mv` instead the normal `mv` to rename files. Then git will know that the file was renamed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, add both the deleted and created file and then run a diff on the index:

```
git add oldname newname
git diff --cached oldname newname
```

If the files are too different, the diff will show them separately, otherwise will show them as a single file updated (with a new name, and some updated content).

Also, as @YesThatIsMyName mentioned, you can do the file renaming in Git directly using `git mv oldname newname` to not have to run `git add oldname newname` after having moved them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **--follow** switch with **git log**. It will show a history of the changes committed, even after renames.

```
git log --follow renamedfile.cs
```

For more info, see [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log).

Also, see this interesting related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743739/how-to-really-show-logs-of-renamed-files-with-git).