# Find first name of a committed, renamed, but never changed file

Tags: git

I have a folder that contains many files, which have seen many renames, but never a change in their content. Is there a way to get back to first name of a given file, or, even better, have a history of the file names over time ?

Comment: Have you looked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743739/how-to-really-show-logs-of-renamed-files-with-git ?

Comment: Hmmm...
... This is not what my question is about, I'm looking for the case when the files don't change. And the answers to that question are essentially "you can't". So, sorry, this is not helpful.

Comment: Read *all* the answers, especially the long one from VonC. Your answer is there.