# Can Git restructure my folders without losing history?

Tags: git

I have a git repo, and currently I'm the only one using it.
I want to take all the files and folders under the root folder, and put them inside a new folder.

Current structure:

```
main ->
  src
  res
```

New structure:

```
main ->
  app1
    src
    res
```

Is there a way I can do that so that the files don't lose their git history?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2314757/359059) shows you how to see history before rename/move.

Comment: just do `git add -A .` after you have moved folder/files. Make sure you don't do any edits.

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314652/is-it-possible-to-move-rename-files-in-git-and-maintain-their-history

Comment: I had some similar problems. All answers seem to be missing some details, but did help me figure it out. I had to mkdir, git add {directory}, git mv ..., git commit, then check the old histories with git log --follow filename.  Telling git to add the new directory before moving files into it made a big difference, even though it was empty and git status didn't show it before or after.  (This should be the answer, but I'm not going to try to add a new answer 4 years later.)

Comment: @Kenny Ostrom not true, `git add {empty directory}` is a NOOP. Anyways, it *sucks* to have to use `--follow` just because we moved files

Answer (score 56, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Go ahead: move your files and directories around. Just make sure you don't make any edits to files in the same commit as your directory restructuring.

#### Why It Works

Git is a content tracker, not a file tracker. If you move/rename files, but make no other changes to the *content* of those files, then Git just [rewrites the tree objects](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects). The file blobs are not changed by directory operations; directory location information is stored separately in tree objects.

Actual rename detection is handled by [diffing the blobs and trees](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitdiffcore), and looking for a configurable percentage of similarity between files. This means that Git doesn't really store moves or renames directly; it *computes* them from differences between commits.

The upshot of all this is that your history is not tied to a particular filename or directory structure. This works really well for most use cases, but stands in contrast to systems like [Bazaar](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/BzrFeatures) that track renames as first-class operations.

Comment: When renaming a parent, I lose the history on the child files?

Comment: @Cian You either didn't understand the answer, are doing something wrong, or have an unusual edge case. You should open a new question with as much detail and supporting evidence as you can provide.

Comment: I may have a strange case, or have misunderstood - I'll take a look in more detail and post a Q. Cheers

Comment: Git only detected renames done with git mv, for me.  Furthermore, since the original question involved a mkdir (and my problem was similar), I had to git add {empty directory name} before moving files.

Comment: @CodeGnome git does track changes and movements. I did a small check and it seems it works. You can check this commit https://github.com/aoancea/git-history/commit/5ee8487733771a714e4b374b38b5db762d406ee1

Comment: For clarity: do you move your files and directories around using `git mv` or simply `mv`?  If I use `git mv` and commit, git log only shows the last commit for any given file.  If I use `mv`, git status shows deleted files.

Answer (score 7):

You can just move the files and Git will (or should) notice that the move has happened. It will keep the history.

If it *doesn't* notice the move for some reason you could try using the diff with `--find-copies-harder` option.

Comment: This answer is correct. Git can help you a bit if you do `mkdir app1 && git mv src res app1 && git commit`. Assuming you actually have some files in both `src` and `res` (if not, git ignores the empty dirs).

Answer (score 3):

When I moved or renamed some files, I lost histories too. But I was trying to reach on **TortoiseGit** and **SourceTree** application.

When I tried to reach on git bash command, I figure out that I can see the history.

```
$Git log
```

After spending a couple of hour on the internet about the reason, Finally, I found my answer.

Tortoise git default settings, showing us just actual files history. I meant, if you rename of if you move any file or folder, you can not see history.
For the seeing history, you have to click below check box on the TortoiseGit settings.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Though this is an older question, I have experienced the marked answer as incorrect. Any folder moves using native commands will result in a "delete" and "add". However, git mv is what you would want to use.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv

In the above case, it would be

```
git mv "main\src" "main\app1\"
```