# Change the root directory of a Git repository

Tags: git, repository

I've got the following source structure:

```
/dir1
    file1
    file2
    file3
```

`dir1` is unneeded as the repository itself can be like a folder, so I want my git repository to look like this:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

What should I do to achieve this?

Comment: Can you not just move the files and do a git add.  Git will know if the files are the same.  You will lose the history, but can get it using git log --follow /path/to/file.  Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314652/is-it-possible-to-move-rename-files-in-git-and-maintain-their-history

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER: this will rewrite history and be a PITA for anyone who has already cloned your repository. You shouldn't do it on published history.**

That said, you should be able to rewrite all your trees by using the [`filter-branch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) command of Git. Be sure to understand all implications before using it (please, read the manpage; have backups).

```
git filter-branch \
  --subdirectory-filter dir1 \
  --tag-name-filter cat \
  -- --all
```

NB. This command will also perist your grafts and replace refs.

Comment: @BoA: hum. I thought I have written a disclaimer at the top of my answer. And advised you to read the manpage and understand the implications of this command. Have I been unclear about that?

Comment: I did read it. I just forgot to add the `-f` flag for `git push`.

Answer (score 7):

You can move your .git in the subdirectory (don't forget your .gitignore).
Then run git init :

Important :
Do a last commit before moving (i'll explain it...)

```
mv .git ./dir1/.
git init .
git add .
git commit
```

It's important to do a last commit before moving : git uses the hash of files to recognize them. unchanged files are seen as 'renamed'.
If you have uncomitted files before moving, it will log them a couple 'deleted' 'added' for each modified file and you'll loose history on those.