# How to rename a Git revisioned file from Netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans

Using Netbeans 7.2, How can I rename (Refactor->Rename) a class/file from Netbeans IDE so that it will be commited as a File Rename/Move and not a file "added" (and the deleted file will actually be repulled on the next pull)

Comment: git has no rename: `git mv` actually does an `add` and an `rm` behind the scenes, renames are "detected". You mean to say Netbeans only does the `add` and not the `rm`? What does `git status` say when you rename a file in NetBeans?

Comment: When you do a "Refactor->Rename" in NetBeans, it is equivalent to using `git mv` on the command line. Are you sure that you commited the change in both the source and destination directories?

Comment: @fge is right.. a 'git mv' is just like 'add' and 'rm'  ..  my problem seems that when I did my commit, I only did it on the renamed(new) file  so the 'rm' was not commited.

Comment: @xblitz if that is really the case, it looks like a serious bug in NetBeans' handling of git repos... Or did you do the commit by hand?

Comment: @fge it's just a case of bad usage on my part I would say because I right clicked on the newly renamed file to do a commit (where as I should have rightclicked on the project) so I only had THAT file in the modification list..

Comment: Ah, OK, that makes more sense. I'd have been really surprised if this kind of bug didn't go unnoticed ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

answering my own question which is actually due to bad usage on my part but might still help others...

First:  `git mv` which is used to move/rename files actually only does `rm` then `add` to a file then you can still maintain revision history to the file by doing a `git log --follow` explained in this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314652/is-it-possible-to-move-rename-files-in-git-and-maintain-their-history)

Second: when using Netbeans with git, renaming (with Refactor->Rename) a file will do the appropriate git commands but be sure to do a commit from either the project folder or Source Folder (right click in the project/file tree) that contains both the old and new file/location so that your commit includes the `remove` and `add/rename` actions for the implicated files.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but just to stress on xblitx answer and to help others in future, 
After Refactor/Rename
Right click on the package of the action -> Git -> Show Changes
You should see all the actions(Delete and Renamed/Modified)
Commit all of them.