# How to preserve history on bitbucket while moving files within a repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

I would like to restructure some files within my git repo while preserving the history of these files on bitbucket.

I have read the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314652/is-it-possible-to-move-rename-files-in-git-and-maintain-their-history) where it was advised to use the `git log --follow` command. However bitbucket doesn't seem to be able to use the follow flag.

Is there any other way to preserve the history while moving files within a repository ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is a request in progress precisely for that feature:

[issue 589: File history should follow copies and renames](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/589/file-history-should-follow-copies-and).

It doesn't seem to be implemented yet though.