# Migrate projects from existing Git repo to restructured Git repo

Tags: git, migration

I have multiple projects in a Git repo as shown below

```
ProjA
 |- file1
 |- dir1/file2
 |-dir2/file3

ProjB
 |- fileA
 |-dirB/file4
```

I need to migrate those projects to a new Git repo, which should have the following structure:

```
 NewProj
  |-- ProjA --| -file1
              |-file2
              |- file3
  |--ProjB --|-file4
             |--NewDir/fileA
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, simple move the files in both projects ProjA and ProjB to their final destination. git should be able to detect those changes. Maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314652/is-it-possible-to-move-rename-files-in-git-and-maintain-their-history) is of help. If you have a remote repository, push it.

Afterwards, create a new repository in an empty folder

```
git init NewProj
```

Add the two previous projects as submodules to your new repository:

```
git submodule add <<path to repo>>
```

Done. You can find some information about submodules [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).