# Git: I want to refactor my codebase, and create new files structures and move things around. Will my git history be maintained?

Tags: git, repository

I'm planning to wholesale refactor my entire project.

It may mean some file renaming, but mostly it will involve a lot of re-organizing of files.

New directories being created, files moving from one directory to another, or from one to a new directory etc.

Will git and my repo maintain it's history under these changes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to move/rename files in git and maintain their history?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314652/is-it-possible-to-move-rename-files-in-git-and-maintain-their-history)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refactor in GIT and move files but still keep track of their history you need to use `git mv`.

Due to the way that git manages the content (It save in different places the content and the metadata of the file names) you **must** do it using `git mv`

Once you do `git mv` and move files to their new location git will mark the files as renamed which means that its still keeping its history but the file was renamed - not the content simply the file name/path

Comment: so if I have a file /project/alpha/myfile, I would first move it to project/beta/myfile, then use git mv, and finally git add/commit/push?

Comment: Almost - move it with git mv and it will move your files to the new location.

Comment: I disagree! If you (mostly) didn't change the content of the files, you could move the files without 'git mv' and it will find out the rename/moving when you add the files to the stage area (based on the similarity).

Comment: You can do it by simply moving the files but the preferred way is to use `git mv` to be sure that it behave as expected.

Comment: @codeWizard Weird. I moved every single file via `git mv`. However, after check in, nothing has retained history. For example if I did a `git mv /dirA/fileZ dirB/`, and then I open up bitbucket and browse my repo, and look at fileZ, it no longer has any history except for the most recent commit.