# Tracking simultaneous move and delete in Git

Tags: git

I have two files `A` (containing *foo*) and `B` (containing *bar*). I want to **delete** `A` and **rename** `B` to `A` so that I'm left with one file called `A` containing *bar*. And I want Git to track of the history of the *bar* text.

However Git treats it as if `B` has been deleted and `A` changed, thereby losing the content history.

By way of example:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/tamlyn/git-test/.git/

$ echo foo > A.txt

$ echo bar > B.txt

$ git add .

$ git commit -m "Initial"
[master (root-commit) 043862d] Initial
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 A.txt
 create mode 100644 B.txt

$ git mv B.txt C.txt

$ git commit -m "Moved"
[master 5a74a66] Moved
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename B.txt => C.txt (100%)

$ git rm A.txt
rm 'A.txt'

$ git mv C.txt A.txt

$ git commit -m "Move and delete"
[master 6b653a9] Move and delete
 2 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 2 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 C.txt

$ git log --stat -M
commit 6b653a91732ea0be92cc1e4e8d6b2af1a1133c70
Author: Tamlyn Rhodes <tamlyn@***.org>
Date:   Wed Dec 9 15:46:16 2015 +0000

    Move and delete

 A.txt | 2 +-
 C.txt | 1 -
 2 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 2 deletions(-)

commit 5a74a663acd8563f8d2217de7369c89a591a7827
Author: Tamlyn Rhodes <tamlyn@***.org>
Date:   Wed Dec 9 15:45:43 2015 +0000

    Moved

 B.txt => C.txt | 0
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

commit 043862d818562b23f4ef43c3fac36b7c384e0d89
Author: Tamlyn Rhodes <tamlyn@***.org>
Date:   Wed Dec 9 15:45:13 2015 +0000

    Initial

 A.txt | 1 +
 B.txt | 1 +
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
```

Comment: Every time I see a Git question I think of [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1597/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to move/rename files in git and maintain their history?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314652/is-it-possible-to-move-rename-files-in-git-and-maintain-their-history)

Comment: @Kristján thanks but I don't think that answers my question. Please see my sample shell output for details.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "losing the content history". However, is it possible to break the deletion of `B.txt` into a single commit, then move `C.txt` to `B.txt` in its own commit?