# In a git repository, how to remove old renamed"capitalization" folders without losing Git history

Tags: git, gitlab, rename

I have a git repository, on which I changed a folder's name to all lower caps.
I successfully pushed the change, and when I do a git pull, I only get the new folder name, but when I go to gitlab and I view my branch, I have both folders Foo and foo on my branch.

How do I purge this from my repository?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to move/rename files in Git and maintain their history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314652/is-it-possible-to-move-rename-files-in-git-and-maintain-their-history)

Comment: I'm sure the reason is some files faile to change their path. Check the Foo contents

Comment: I don't know easy way to fix it at  case-insensitive filesystem... maybe somebody has an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we do 
`git log --follow [file]`
we are able to see the file renaming history, but this is not an answer to the question that I asked initialy.

Essentially, it is not possible to do so

Answer (score 0):

If depends on your remote repository hosting service.

On GitLab, for instance, you can go to the folder you don't want, and you can delete the files there: that folder will then disappear.

It would be easier to have a "delete" button for the folder itself, but that is still pending ([issue 3518](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/3518))

The idea remains: try and fix the issue on the remote side (the Git repo hosting service) instead of locally (the local clone).
Then clone again.