# Replay git commits of one file on top of another (kind of git copy file commits)

Tags: git

I've forked project where I rewrote 90% of huge `Makefile`. After reviewing my pull request, upstream maintainer proposed me to put all my changes in a new makefile beside of original to have a transition period.

Since I worked on main `Makefile` it now has tens of my commits and now I should jump to a branching point, make a copy of original file as `Makefile.new` and somehow apply all my commits on top of this new file to retain a history of my changes. Then I should revert all my changes from original `Makefile` to retain its own history.

This isn't a case for rebasing, so I'm not sure how it can be achieved without handpicking all my commits.

Comment: Maybe check [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314652/is-it-possible-to-move-rename-files-in-git-and-maintain-their-history).

Comment: `git mv` deletes original file which should still exist. New file should be a copy which start its history at branching point.

Comment: yeah, it's a complex matter, I've erased my simplistic comment and linked to a better analysis.

Comment: It's really a bit beyond `git mv` and `git rebase`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just keep your branch history as is, and then add two new commits:

```
mv Makefile MAkefile.new
git add .
git commit
git checkout master -- Makefile
git commit
```

This will preserve your history, revert Makefile to its original state, and put your changed version under the new name.

The reason to do it in 2 commits is so that rename detection can "follow' what happened, making it easier to see the history of MAkefile.new specifically.  If this isn't a concern - if your team typically looks at full patches to understand history - then you could do it in a single commit just as well.

Comment: This is good and straightforward solution, I'll consider it if no other will be proposed. There only one downside for me: original `Makefile` will share all commit history of `Makefile.new` which was a `Makefile` before `git mv` point. My target is completely separate commit histories for both files.

Comment: @stunpix - The ship for "completely separate commit histories' sailed when you started making commits that introduced your changes at the existing file's path.  To get that now, you would need a history rewrite - which in a shared repo, has some rather exterme costs.  If you want to understand what's involved in that, the command you'd use is `git filter-branch`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me on `git filter-branch`. It done for me absolutely all what I needed.

Comment: This is what I've done: `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'cp Makefile Makefile.new && git checkout master -- Makefile' HEAD~31..HEAD`