# I want to move all the content from the folder to one-level up in the hierarchy and delete the previous folder in GitHub

Tags: git, github

```
I have a git repository whose structure looks like:
+--- .git
+-- PracticeProject
+- PracticeFramework
+----+log
+----+testdata
+----+test-output
+----+lib
```

And i want it to like the below code. We are removing the folder - PracticeFramework

```
+--- .git
+--PracticeProject
+----+log
+----+testdata
+----+test-output
+----+lib
```

Comment: Don't understand the one-level up. To remove a folder, git rm -r PracticeFramework

Comment: means i want to add all the files which is in the "PracticeFramework" folder to "PracticeProject" folder and remove "PracticeFramework" folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to preserve history, use `git mv` and `git rm`.

```
git mv PracticeFramework/* PracticeProject
git rm -r PracticeFramework
```

The first line moves all the files from `PracticeFramework` to `PracticeProject`.

The second line removes `PracticeProject`.

EDIT: according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2314757/5954825), `git mv` or `mv` doesn't really matter.

Comment: encountered this error:-
C:\Users\saniket.soni\git\Practice_Project\PracticeFramework>git mv PracticeFramework/* Practice_Project
fatal: bad source, source=PracticeFramework/PracticeFramework/*, destination=PracticeFramework/Practice_Project

Comment: Its "Practice_Project" not "PracticeProject"

Comment: @SaniketA.Soni according to your question, it's PracticeProject. Also, try to run the commands from C:\Users\saniket.soni\git, not from C:\Users\saniket.soni\git\Practice_Project\PracticeFramework>