# Git how to see who created and moved files to a directory

Tags: git, directory

Some files in our project are moved to a directory which is not the correct place for them. I would like to see who was the creator of the directory and who moved the files.

For some files this is the correct place, so I would like to see the moving date and the user who moved them for every single file. Is this possible with git bash?

Comment: It's kind of harmless to use it, but note that the pop-up tag info for [tag:history] says DO NOT USE THIS TAG...

Comment: Than you, I will remove it. I thought I can use history as "git log history".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try at least a [`git log --follow -- a_renamed_file`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2314757/6309) inside the new directory (the incorrect one)

That will give you an idea of the commit in which that file was moved/renamed (assuming its content was the same or very similar)

You can then see the author of that commit, who likely created the destination folder.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. I just used log on the whole directory but there were too many changes to find the commit.

Comment: @ChrisCrozz Exactly: filtering by file is more precise.