# Remove files from origin after mv instead of git mv

Tags: git

I am trying to restructure my code and did `mv` to move files to directories.

This lead to git having duplicate files, both in the original directory and in the moved directory.

How do I ensure that the files in the "original" directory are deleted on the remote but kept in the moved directory?

Comment: Was your repo clean when you started moving files around ? If yes, a simple `git add .` should do the right thing.

Comment: Does `git add .` or `git add -A` not solve this? It automatically resolves that files have been moved for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a clean work tree before you did the file movement (this can be checked using `git status` before moving files), simply running

```sh
git add -A
```

should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add your new file and remove the old file from the repository.

```sh
git add newFolder/newFile.html
git rm oldFolder/oldFile.html
```

**EDIT**:

Regarding this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314652/is-it-possible-to-move-rename-files-in-git-and-maintain-their-history) it makes no difference whether you run `git mv` or `mv`. Git should recognise that. So it should be possible to push the movements of the files with:

```sh
git add -A
```