# Moving files between branches with preserving history in git

Tags: git

I have *BranchA* which was cut off from master 6 months ago. On specific file: *BranchA* -> dir1/dir2/abc.txt was done like 300 commits.  Meantime on *master* was done like 3000 commits, but none of them touched *master* -> dir1/dir2/abc.txt. A few days ago was created a new branch from *master* -> *BranchB*. I try to move a file from *BranchA* -> dir1/dir2/abc.txt to *BranchB* -> dir1/dir2/abc.txt and have all its history of commits that were done on *BranchA* -> dir1/dir2/abc.txt.

Sometimes commit on the file *BranchA* -> dir1/dir2/abc.txt was done with few other files but I am not interested in it.

How I can move the file from *BranchA* to *BranchB* with preserving history?

Comment: Please consider changing how you think about git history. In git, commits _are the history_. A branch is a label for a specific commit, which can be moved. A commit is a snapshot _of the entire repo_. --- All that being said https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314652/is-it-possible-to-move-rename-files-in-git-and-maintain-their-history

Comment: Sorry. My syntax could be confusing. I changed it. Right now name in italic style means name of branch.

Comment: *Git* does not have pull requests. GitHub (the hosting site) provide Pull Requests; Bitbucket (a different hosting site) provide something very similar but not identical but also called Pull Requests. Approval policies for pull requests are host-specific, and the way you get approvals depends on whose project it is. You should figure out who owns this project and ask them how to get approval - don't just ask random strangers on StackOverflow!

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear. I mentioned PR to give a brief context why we don't merge stuff properly from BranchA to master and later from master to BranchB. As I can see it was bewildering.